# How the Typescript function parameter works?

Tags: typescript, function

```
function greeter(fn: (a: string ) => void) {
  fn("Hello, World");
}
 
function printToConsole() {
  console.log(1);
}
 
greeter(printToConsole);
```

I am new in typescript and the above really confuses me.

The function greeter needs another function as parameter which takes a string

The function printToConsole is a function without any parameter.

Why greeter can accept printToConsole as a parameter?

I expect an error from complier

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of research, it looks like that `printToConsole` doesn't need a parameter because you just simply print the number "1" and you don't actually use the argument passed to `fn`.
TypeScript allows this kind of behavior because the callback functions signature and the function you give as an argument do the same thing. You don't use the argument defined in the callback's signature, so you could say that `fn` has no parameter as well and both functions return nothing.

Answer (score 0):

##### you can  define  a Generics to calculate the incoming parameters

```
// eslint-disable-next-line space-before-function-paren
function greeter<T extends (a: string) => void>(fn: ParamsType<T>) {
  fn('Hello, World');
}

function printToConsole() {
  console.log(1);
}

/**
 * @returns {the ts complier will report ts 2345 error }
 * @example {Argument of type '() => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Error'.ts(2345)}
 */
greeter(printToConsole);

type ParamsType<T> = T extends (...args: infer Args) => any ? (Args[0] extends string ? T : Error) : Error;
```

Comment: It does not work with the original `function printToConsole() {
  console.log(1);
}`

Comment: oh, thanks , I forgot to delete